# Is it possible to make a macro that replaces newlines with semicolons

Tags: c++, macros

Say someone was really lazy and didn't want to have to keep remembering to type semi-colons at the end of a line, is there a way to get past that with macros?

I'm not saying it's something I want to do. Just curious if anyone's tried it/if it's possible.

Something like:

```
#define '\n'  ';\n'
```

Comment: There are lots of EOLs that semicolons would screw up.

Comment: forget about it, replacing newlines would get you into infinite loop assuming you managed to get it to work in the first place

Comment: @MahmoudFayez, Only if you went through recursively. Doing a simple regex replacement on the contents of a file would finish.

Comment: So they can't remember to type semicolons, but they'll remember to type the macro instead?

Comment: @Barmar I think he means something like `/\n/;\n/` just to add semicolons

Answer (score 2):

No, macro identifiers can only be letters, numbers, and underscores.

Additionally, this would result in tons of unnecessary semicolons

```
if (cond)
    stmt;
/* or */
if (cond)
{
    stmts;
}
```

Would be ruined by this theoretical macro.

If you wanted to replace all newlines with a semicolon followed by a newline (which is a **really bad idea**) you could do it with a sed line

```
sed -i "s/^\([^#].*[^\;{]\)$/\1;/" file.cpp
```

this will add a semi colon to the end of any line:

1. Not already ending in a semi colon
2. Not beginning with `#`
3. Not ending with a `{`

Though this is still not perfect. there will always be situations where you don't want to end with a semi colon, it would cause the code to not compile, though this is better than the ifs being empty statements as above.

```
int var = //like here
    some_value;

func(arg1, arg2, // and here
     arg3, arg4);

int func()  // and here too
{
    //body
}
```

Comment: Statements like that are a bad idea, so they deserve to be ruined. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't automatically need a semicolon at the end of every line.

There isn't going to be a way to write a C pre-processor macro that replaces newlines with semicolons because C macro names have to be identifiers — a sequence of alphanumeric characters (plus underscore) started with a non-numeric character.

You'd have to do:

```
#define SC ;

int x = 0 SC
```

which is worse than the problem you're trying to fix.